# How to use os.getenv() (from python) in c++?

Tags: python, c++, operating-system

I'm not searching for an equivalent of **os librar**y from python in c++ as well! How to use os.getenv() (from python) in c++?

Comment: This is strictly off-topic, read the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ provides native access to the environment via the [`std::getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) function. You generally don't *need* to call the Python version from your C++ programs.

Comment: That was not my question! thanks anyways!